# How to use post method in Twig syntax

Tags: javascript, php, json, twig

Hi I am trying to convert tpl file into twig syntax following code which uses twig .
My question is is it possible to use post function in twig syntax?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){$('#jb-cancel-order').click(function(){
 if(confirm('Are you sure want to cancel this?')) {
 $.post('index.php?route=account/order/jbcancelorder',{order_id: {{order_id}},email:'{{customer_email}}'},function(e){
if(e.status=='ok'){
    $('#jb-cancel-order').remove();
}
},'json');
}
return false;
});});
</script>]]>
```

While running the webpage its only showing popup message without any action as expected.Cancellation is not fired.Post method is not working. Reference code: https://github.com/jericbas/jb_allow_order_cancel_24_hours

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is that jQuery? Is jQuery included?

Comment: Is this script inside a twig template? Did you check your developer console for (syntax) errors

Comment: script is inside twig template.I have modified tpl code to twig as mentioned in the link https://github.com/jericbas/jb_allow_order_cancel_24_hours.I am using opencart and vqmod log file is not showing any errors.

Comment: I'm referring to the console in your browser

Comment: Yes script is inside twig template.